# Save Many to many relationships between two models in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I have two models which has many to many relationship. 
And I created repository, service, and controller layers for each one.
Now when I make a POST request to each one of them, it is created, but how can we make 
a connection between them since there is a third table created that contains PKs of each one of the models.
The same goes with GET request, it return an empty List.

Can Anyone explain to me how can I POST and GET in two models that have many to many relationships and make link between them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your implementation of JPA you can achieve the relationship just by annotating the model fields. For example here I use Hibernate and java.persitence annotations to immplement the relationship.
I have a class `Account` which has a list of `Subject`s. Likewise my `Subject` has a list of `Account`s as a field. To map the relationship I use the java.persitence annotations in this way:

Class Account.java

```
private List<Subject> subjects;

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(
    name = "account_subject", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "account_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id") }
)
public List<Subject> getSubjects() {
    if(subjects == null) {
        return new LinkedList<Subject>();
    }
    return subjects;
}
```

Class Subject.java

```
private List<Account> accounts;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subjects")
public List<Account>  getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}
```

This will automaticlly create a join table called `account_subject` containing two columns `account_id` and `subject_id`, and the line `cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }` will ensure any operation (update, delete etc..) will be performed on both entities.

To save an Account entity using Hibernate you simply have to set the required field, for example :

```
List<Subject> mySubjects = new List<Subject>();
mySubjects.add(mySubject);
myAccount.setSubjects(mySubjects);
```

and in you repository class we use the Hibernate method `saveOrUpdate()` to persist

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(myAccount);
```

where `sessionFactory` is your Hibernate SessionFactory object.

Comment: I did the same relations as you mentioned above, but regarding to the repository i have an interface extends from jpa..??? Is that correct?and how can i used this sessionfactory??

Comment: In that case you can just call `repositoryImpl.save(myAccount)` where repositoryImpl is your repository class which implements the JPA interface. Normally you would inject this into your service class with @Autowired and make this call to repositoryImpl from there.